# Html5 tag Video does not work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, html5-video

the tag  is working fine on firefox and IE Explorer, however does not work on Chrome. I have two video formats, mp4 and webm.,

Here is the html

```
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="8.jpg" id="bgvid">

    <source src="8.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="8.webm" type="video/webm">

</video>
```

And my css

```
video#bgvid { 
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background: url(8.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover; 
}
```

If you want to see a live version, you can find it here.

https://neevasoft.com/icedrink2/

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: "Not found" for 8.jpg could be the reason.

Comment: Your Website loaded the video, But because of the poster its not showing. The poster is missing in your website. Please check it by removing the poster.

Comment: I don't think the missing poster is the problem. Works fine on codepen and the poster is 404'ing https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/JNqyLK

Comment: @MichaelCoker, could be one of the other errors the Chrome console is reporting. It's certainly quite strange.

Comment: yeah I'm thinking it is, or they have some javascript stopping it or something. If OP took the trouble to reproduce the problem in their post, I bet they'd figure it out.

Comment: I tried all of that, but still the same... It is weird...

Answer (score 0):

Your source file links aren't working. If you're using the above url for your src attribute you need to put the videos at the same level of your index.html file and there isn't any videos at this level in your file structure. Alternatively place them in one of the folders and change the src url accordingly.

[image]

Comment: What anchor links are you referring to, and what do they have anything to do with the video not working? Can you provide a code solution for OP?

Comment: His source for the video is <source src="8.mp4" type="video/mp4">, but there are no video files at this location in his file structure?  Surely that must be the problem?

Comment: The video is there, but doesn't show there at the source. 

https://neevasoft.com/icedrink2/video/8a.mp4 - You can see them there. and https://neevasoft.com/icedrink2/video/8.webm

Comment: that is not the link in your source tag though.  You need to use that link in your source tag.

Comment: I have changed - 
<source src="video/8.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video/8a.mp4" type="video/mp4">

But still the same...